# std::bad_cast pointer vs reference situation

Tags: c++, exception

I've noticed with regard to the std::bad_cast exception that references and pointers don't seem to act the same way.  For example:

```
class A { public: ~A() {} };
class B : public A {};

//Case #1
int main()
{
    A a;
    B& b = dynamic_cast<B&>(a);  //Would throw std::bad_cast.
}

//Case #2
int main()
{
    A* a = new A;
    B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a);  //Would not throw std::bad_cast.
}
```

In the first case, an exception of std::bad_cast is generated, and in the second case no exception is generated - instead, the b pointer just is assigned the value NULL.

Can someone explain to me why only the former throws an exception when both are bad_cast examples?  I figure there's a good motive behind the decision, and that I'm misusing something as I don't understand that motivation.

Comment: How else would you do it? Use pointers when you're just checking, without prejudice, and it's normal for the cast to fail. On the other had, use references when you know the cast should succeed, and catch the exception at an appropriate checkpoint.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Can someone explain to me why only the former throws an exception?

That is how `dynamic_cast` is specified to behave:  a bad `dynamic_cast` involving pointers yields a null pointer, but there are no null references, so a bad `dynamic_cast` involving references throws a `bad_cast`.

The fact that a failed `dynamic_cast` involving pointers yields a null pointer is useful because it allows for cleaner, simpler type checking and allows for the following idiom:

```
if (B* b = dynamic_cast<B*>(a))
{
    // The dynamic_cast succeeded and 'b' is non-null.
}
```

With this idiom, `b` is in scope and usable if and only if it is non-null.

Comment: Though normally we would consider doing that bad programming technique, as we are branching based on `runtime type` rather than using virtual functions.

Comment: @LokiAstari:  I think it depends on the situation.  Certainly virtual functions should be preferred where they are usable.

Answer (score 2):

References must be bound to an object that contains a valid memory address ... they cannot be "uninitialized", nor do they have a default non-bound initialization values.  Note that section 8.5/8 in the C++11 standard states,

> A program that calls for default-initialization or value-initialization of an entity of reference type is ill-formed.

Pointer variables on the other-hand are just memory addresses that contain values that point to other memory addresses and therefore can have a `NULL` value.

So if by the standard the `dynamic_cast<T&>` operation must return a valid memory address to bind to the reference variable, then if the dynamic cast fails, it can't return a "non-value" ... the only option is to throw an exception.